# One to many relation in EF Core

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I tried to study Entity Framework when learning .net core mvc I like to undestand what it the best practice to create a one-to-many table relations:

Here are the 2 models:

```
    public class BookCategory
    {
        [Key]
        public int IdCategory { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Description { get; set; }

    }

 public class Book
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Author { get; set; }
        public string ISBN { get; set; }
        public int IdCategory { get; set; }
        public BookCategory BookCategory { get; set; }

    }


        // dBContext
        public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
        public DbSet<BookCategory> BookCategories { get; set; }
```

I am not sure if this is the best way to create a relation in mvc because after update-database call I see the field "BookCategoryIdCategory" in "book" table and I don't think this is correct.

Can you help me please ?

Update: I forget to explain better:

In my database after update-database I like to see:

```
(table book)

    int Id (primary key)
    string Name 
    string Author
    string ISBN
    int IdCategory (relation with IdCategory of BookCategory

(table bookcategory)

int IdCategory (primary key relation with IdCategory of book)
string Description
```

and if possible no other fields.

Comment: This is an EF question, not an ASP.NET question: Entity Framework has nothing do with ASP.NET MVC or ASP.NET Core. I've edited your question.

Comment: This page explains what you need to do: https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/one-to-many-relationship-configuration - you need to add an `ICollection<Book>` property to `BookCategory` and set-up the relationship in `OnModelCreating`.

Comment: I don't think it can be anything other than a many-to-many relationship.

Comment: Dai, thank you for your response, in your link there is no "IDCompany" or similar  field. My questions are: Is your link the best way ? And If I need to use "IDCompany" ? Others suggest a "list". Why this way is better then others ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your scenario,you could use `ForeignKey` attribute.The `ForeignKey` attribute is used to specify which property is the foreign key in a relationship:

```
public class Book
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string ISBN { get; set; }
    public int IdCategory { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("IdCategory")]         //add this...
    public BookCategory BookCategory { get; set; }
}
public class BookCategory
{
    [Key]
    public int IdCategory { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If a BookCategory can have many Books then one could say it has a List of Books.

In your Book Category class, add:

```
public List<Book> Books { get; set; }
```